# How to efficiently sum two columns in a file with 270,000+ rows in bash

Tags: bash, unix, solaris, performance

I have two columns in a file, and I want to automate summing both values per row

for example

```
read write
5    6
read write
10   2
read write
23   44
```

I want to then sum the "read" and "write" of each row. Eventually after summing, I'm finding the max sum and putting that max value in a file. I feel like I have to use grep -v to rid of the column headers per row, which like stated in the answers, makes the code inefficient since I'm grepping the entire file just to read a line.

I currently have this in a bash script (within a for loop where $x is the file name) to sum the columns line by line

```
lines=`grep -v READ $x|wc -l | awk '{print $1}'`
line_num=1
arr_num=0


while [ $line_num -le $lines ]
do

    arr[$arr_num]=`grep -v READ $x |  sed $line_num'q;d' | awk '{print $2 + $3}'`
    echo $line_num
    line_num=$[$line_num+1]
    arr_num=$[$arr_num+1]

done
```

However, the file to be summed has 270,000+ rows. The script has been running for a few hours now, and it is nowhere near finished. Is there a more efficient way to write this so that it does not take so long?

Comment: Bit unorthodox.. import into database and SUM from there?

Comment: It isn't clear what the hang-up with READ is; I suspect you're not telling us the whole story about the input data format.

Comment: Your script is reading the entire file to extract a single line, for each line. No wonder it's taking long.

Comment: Calling `grep`, `sed` and `awk` for each iteration of the while loop is likely a major contributor to your performance issue.  Especially considering the `grep` is effectively reading the entire file in each iteration

Comment: Do you need to know what the line number is? What exactly is the format of the output you want?

Comment: I'm glad I took data structures. I wouldn't have had a clue about time-complexity and would keep making these types of mistakes.

Comment: When I asked this question when it was relevant to me about 1.5 years ago, I didn't know anything about cs, data structures, or time complexity. I ended up answering my own question with what worked for me at the time. Even though my answer was still inefficient (which I didn't know at the time), it ran much more quickly than what I had posted in the question, so I ended up going with my answer. When I get home from work tonight I can try out the other answers and mark a new accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) instead and take advantage of *modulus* function:

```
awk '!(NR%2){print $1+$2}' infile
```

Comment: I changed the format of the source file in my question since that is relevant. I forgot to mention that. This is why I have to use grep

Answer (score 3):

`awk` is probably faster, but the idiomatic [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) way to do this is something like:

```
while read -a line; do      # read each line one-by-one, into an array
                            # use arithmetic expansion to add col 1 and 2
    echo "$(( ${line[0]} + ${line[1]} ))"
done < <(grep -v READ input.txt)
```

Note the file input file is only read once (by `grep`) and the number of externally forked programs is kept to a minimum (just `grep`, called only once for the whole input file).  The rest of the commands are `bash` builtins.

Using the `<( )` process substition, in case variables set in the while loop are required out of scope of the while loop.  Otherwise a `|` pipe could be used.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to give this a try Friday now. I'll give you more credit when I try it then.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty verbose, yet your goal is not clear. The way I read it, your numbers are on every second line, and you want only to find the maximum sum. Given that:

```
awk '
    NR%2 == 1 {next} 
    NR == 2 {max = $1+$2; next} 
    $1+$2 > max {max = $1+$2}
    END {print max}
' filename
```

Comment: To sum the net of two column, using your method:  awk 'NR>2{sum+=$4-$5}END{print sum}' file

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a pipeline with tools that implicitly loop over the input like so:

```
grep -v read INFILE | tr -s ' ' + | bc | sort -rn | head -1 > OUTFILE
```

This assumes there are spaces between your read and write data values.

Answer (score 0):

Why not run:

```
awk 'NR==1 { print "sum"; next } { print $1 + $2 }'
```

You can afford to run it on the file while the other script it still running.  It'll be complete in a few seconds at most (prediction).  When you're confident it's right, you can kill the other process.

You can use Perl or Python instead of `awk` if you prefer.

Your code is running `grep`, `sed` and `awk` on each line of the input file; that's damnably expensive.  And it isn't even writing the data to a file; it is creating an array in Bash's memory that'll need to be printed to the output file later.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's always one 'header' row followed by one 'data' row:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{ max = 0 }
  {
    if( NR%2 == 0 ){
      sum = $1 + $2;
      if( sum > max ) { max = sum }
    }
  }
  END{ print max }' input.txt
```

Or simply trim out all lines that do not conform to what you want:

```
grep '^[0-9]\+\s\+[0-9]\+$' input.txt | awk '
  BEGIN{ max = 0 }
  {
    sum = $1 + $2;
    if( sum > max ) { max = sum }
  }
  END{ print max }' input.txt
```